# Spaces whose continuous image (into a metric space) is always compact

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, compactness

I am looking for a reference to either of these two kinds of topological spaces (preferably the second one) :

- Topological spaces whose continuous image is compact/pseudocompact
- Topological spaces whose continuous image into a metric space is compact

For the first one, any compact/pseudocompact space is an example since continuity preserves these properties. For the second, pseudocompactness works, since it is preserved by continuity, and a pseudocompact metric space is compact. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I suppose the condition is that $f(X)$ be compact for all continuous $f \colon X \to Y$ where $Y$ is a metric space? Note that you can pick $Y = \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Yes that's absolutely right

Comment: It is true that a space $X$ is pseudocompact if and only if for any metric space $Y$ and any continuous function  $f:X\rightarrow Y$, the image $f(X)\subseteq Y$ is compact. Are you looking for a reference for this fact or a general discussion about pseudocompact spaces?

Comment: @Tyrone I was unaware of that fact. I only knew that pseudocompact spaces are those whose continuous images into $\mathbb{R}$ are bounded.

Comment: The reference is R. M. Stephenson, Jr., *Pseudocompact Spaces*, Trans. Am. Math. Soc.134, (1968), 437-448. See Theorem 2.3.

Comment: @Tyrone This is really helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a metric space a subspace $A$ is pseudocompact iff $A$ is compact. This is classical.

It follows that if $X$ is a pseudocompact topological space and $f:X \to Y$ is continuous and $Y$ is a metric space, then $f[X]$ is pseudocompact (also classical and easy to prove) and so $f[X]$ is compact, by the first fact. The reverse, that if $X$ is a space such that every continuous image into a metric space is compact, then $X$ is pseudocompact is trivial (apply the fact to the metric space $\Bbb R$ and note that compact sets are bounded..).

So both the mentioned properties are just a reformulation of pseudocompactness.

Comment: Yes of course. Thank you.